# A possibly silly question about "custom" integers in C#

Tags: c#

Good afternoon,

This may sound like a silly question, but it would be really useful if there was a way around this... Is there any way I can get custom bit-depth integers (for example, a 20-bit integer) in C#?

Thank you very much.

Comment: not a silly question at all, IMHO

Comment: No, you can't, but if you explain what you need it for there is probably a good alternative.

Comment: If it is technically impossible to have a real "custom" bit-length integer in C#, the OP should be able to define a class or struct with two 64-bit integers as fields.  With appropriate definitions of the operators, it should be possible to do something like what he wants.

Comment: there are libraries for scientific research, I've used one also, to calculate energy levels of atoms. I've used a well known library. But What i need is resolution.

Comment: There are no silly questions - only ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical questions. :)

Comment: What do you need this for? Do you need a specific behavior on overflow? Otherwise simply use int or long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. As most things, the answer will depend on what you need to do with it.

I did something similar years ago maintaining a school research project. We had a custom integer type, though it was not necessarily defined by bit-depth per se. It was a prime-factor (with remainder) representation. This was very handy for what it was supposed to do, which was multiply and divide very large numbers. It was very poor for addition and subtraction.

There are also many other "custom" number implementations out there, a very common one is a custom Fixed Point representation (often seen when implementing deterministic physical simulations in games). There are probably some good overflow posts about this subject. These would be a good start for ideas on how to abstract and then implement a custom numeric representation.

If you are set on variable-bit-depth integer representation, consider wrapping an internal representation. One possibility may be to use an `IEnumerable<byte>` and extend it byte by byte as its magnitude increases. Write operators that work against a dynamic range. This may not necessarily be the most optimal form of representation or most performant, but it would likely be the easiest.

Another possible solution may be to do something similar, but with 'ulong'. Not as space efficient, but we benefit from 64-bit operations.

Just spitballing :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

Build a struct that takes a 32 bit integer and bit masks it with
 `0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`, or (`0x08FF`)
before storing it in an internal private field.

```
   public struct TwentyBitInt
   {
      private const int mask = 0x08FF;
      private int val;
      private bool isDef;


      private TwentyBitInt(int value)
      {
         val = value & mask;
         isDef = true;
      }
      public static TwentyBitInt Make(int value) 
      { return new TwentyBitInt(value); }

      public int Value { get { return val; } }
      public bool HasValue { get { return isDef; } }

      public static TwentyBitInt Null = new TwentyBitInt();

      public static explicit operator int (TwentyBitInt twentyBit)
      { 
          if (!HasValue) throw new ArgumentNullValueException(); 
          return twentyBit.val;
      }
      public static implicit operator TwentyBitInt (int integerValue)
      { return Make(integerValue); }

      // etc.
    }
```

You can also appropriately overload the arithmetic operators so that arithmetic operations behave consistently with the business rules for the domain they are to be used in..

Comment: Nice solution; +1. I think you have the explicit and implicit conversions reversed though; converting from a TwentyBitInt to an int is always possible and can therefore be implicit, whereas converting an int to a TwentyBitInt may not fit and should therefore be explicit.

Comment: I am assuming the opposite, that going frm int to `TwentyBitInt` the application of the mask in the constructor will always strip off the 12 high bits, whereas, from `TwentyBitInt` to int, we have to guard against a null...

Comment: You have a point about the null-check, but comparing it against for instance casting between a long and an int, explicit casts are used where data may be lost (int i = (int)lng;) whereas implicit casts are used otherwise (long lng = i;). Perhaps both should be explicit? Alternatively, the null-logic could be removed and replaced with a default value of 0, making it work more like the regular primitives and allowing for an implicit conversion from TwentyBitInt to int.

Comment: yes, but in this case, as I mentioned, there is no need to ask the user to explicitly cast, as it will always succeed. The INTENT is to lose the extra 12 bits even if they are provided... casting from a long to an int is not the same as there it is not guaranteed that the user's intent is to lose the extra bits... But, in the end, this is up to the designer of the class, based on the business purprose for which he will use it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can but it is not going to be easy. You can use something like a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) to create an arbitrary length bitstring. Then you have to write all the code yourself to treat it like an integer. That's the hard part.

Answer (score 2):

Though you can't create a structure that would fit exactly "20 bits" in memory, you could create your own structure that will "behave like" a 20 bit data type (by storing a private "regular" data type, and using bitwise operators in your public setter to keep only the wanted bits).

```
struct TwoBits
{
    int m_data;

    public int Data
    {
        set
        {
            m_data = 0x03 & value;
        }
        get
        {
            return m_data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out operator overloading and design a custom class (probably more work than you want to do though). http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasadh/OperatorOverloading11142005003229AM/OperatorOverloading.aspx